# Why Can't I drill down to the tag I want using BeautifoulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web

### Why Can't I drill down to the tag I want using BeautifoulSoup

I want to extract the PRODUCT CODE from CME(Chicago Mercantile Exchange).

Q1: I thought I can extract it from table -> tr. But the code only stops at the TRADING HOURS' text. Please guide me how I can go deeper to get the PRODUCT CODE with certain texts.

If it successes, we should be able to see:

**CME Globex: ZC**

**CME ClearPort: C**

**Clearing: C**

**TAS: ZCT**

Q2: Then somehow, I would just need the word **ZC** then put in my csv file.

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
 from urllib.request import Request
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

 AccessCME=Request("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-
 oilseed/corn_contract_specifications.html",headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
 CMEPage=uReq(AccessCME).read()

 page_soup=soup(CMEPage,"html.parser")

 table=page_soup.find("table")
 rows=table.find_all("tr")

 print(rows)
```

If it's not clear, let me know then I will clarify more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno why you got that particular row of the table. However, I can say that you would need to take more care in identifying the row you actually want. I notice that only one is labelled with a term containing the word 'Product'. I decided to hunt for that. I also used the `requests` module since it tends to be less problematic.

First I find all of the `td` elements that *could* be the one I want. Then I identify the one amongst these that has 'Product' in its `text` attribute. I call it `parent_td` when it really should be, say, `sibling_td`. I verify that it contains what I hoped for.

Now I look amongst it siblings for other `td` elements, get its `text` attribute and strip off white space at each end. I display the result as `target`.

Finally I use two `re.sub` invocations, one within the other to discard pieces of this string that I don't want, yielding what you wanted.

This is all unusually awkard.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/grain-and-oilseed/corn_contract_specifications.html').content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> possible_tds = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':"prodSpecAtribute"})
>>> parent_td = [td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text][0]
>>> parent_td
<td class="prodSpecAtribute">Product Code</td>
>>> target = parent_td.fetchNextSiblings('td')[0].text.strip()
>>> target
'CME Globex: ZCCME ClearPort: CClearing: CTAS: ZCT'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'CME Globex:\s+', '', target)
'ZCCME ClearPort: CClearing: CTAS: ZCT'
>>> re.sub(r'CME ClearPort:.*', '', re.sub(r'CME Globex:\s+', '', target))
'ZC'
```

Edit (responses to comments):

Q1: I almost always use `lxml` because it always works, in my experience. I would use something else if I happen to notice that the question involves the use of something else and this appears to be significant.

Q2: `[td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text]` is what is called a *list comprehension*. It has an expression, in this case just a variable `td`, a for-loop, in this case, `for td in possible_tds`, and optionally a condition, in this case, `if 'Product' in td.text`. A list comprehension makes a list of the expressions in it given by the for-loop governed by the condition.

The `possible_tds` came from the previous statement. It's a list of `td` elements in the `soup` that have a certain `class`. The for-loop in the list comprehension looks through these looking for the ones whose `text` attribute contains 'Product'. Those that do are added to the list that becomes `parent_td`. We know there is only one; therefore we ask for the `[0]` item in the list.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was researching on what you did and trying to figure it out. 
Your explanation was clear easy to follow along. But could you help me out here? How can I find out the definition of those small techniques you used? 

For example: 
Q1: I don’t know why you used **lxml**, instead of **HTML**
Q2: I know the logic for **for statement**. But not the methods of yours:
parent_td = [**td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text**][0]
I didn’t see a variable called td above here. So why you can just declare inside of the bracket. What’s the logic here?

Comment: Sorry for the format. I wish I could set it up nicely so you can see it comfortably.

Comment: No apologies needed. Comments fields are not good places to format. Give me a few minutes to answer.

Comment: Roger that! let's see. (Updated: It's wonderful. I understood. Please look at my another post if you are interested in as well.)